# Behavior when not writing ntp.conf restrict

Tags: ntp, ntpd

if I don't write `restrict` in ntp.conf , so ntp `restrict` is Unlimited?

I wrote:

```
interface ignore wildcard
interface listen lo
interface listen lan0
```

man page http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/accopt.html#restrict said:

> A default entry (address 0.0.0.0, mask 0.0.0.0 for IPv4 and address :: mask :: for IPv6) is always the first entry in the list. restrict default, with no mask option, modifies both IPv4 and IPv6 default entries. r

if I don't write restrict, The setting is as follows:

```
restrict 0.0.0.0/0
```

restrict has address/mask, but doesn't flag. ok?

Answer (score 1):

> if I don't write `restrict` in ntp.conf , so ntp `restrict` is Unlimited?

Correct, the default is unrestricted. This allows the control protocol over these interfaces, which may not be desired. A common pattern is allowing time service to any client but modify messages only from localhost:

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 
restrict -6 ::1
```